# Transformation of Observable

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, observable, reactive

I've a data structure which looks like this:

```
 Observable<Array<LineChart>>
```

whereby an LineChart is defined like

```
export interface LineChart  {
  name?: null | string;
  series?: null | Array<DateLineChartEntry>;
}
```

and an DateLineChartEntry is defined like this:

```
export interface DateLineChartEntry  {
  name?: string;
  value?: number;
}
```

where name is string, which contains Date.

For my follow-up operation with this DataStructure i need to convert the DateLineChartEntry to sth. like this:

```
export interface DateLineChartEntryConverted  {
  name?: Date;
  value?: number;
}
```

which means, i've to map all DateLineChartEntries like this

```
DateLineChartEntry  => {
name: new Date(name),
value: value
}
```

My current solutions looks like that:

```
    this.data = getObservable({ body: parameters }).pipe(
  map(lca => {
    var lcaConverted = [];

    for (var lc of lca) {
      var name = lc.name
      var lcN = {
        name: name,
        series: []
      };

      for (var e of lc.series) {
        var n = new Date(e.name);
        lcN.series.push({
          name: n,
          value: e.value
        });
      }

      lcaConverted.push(lcN);
    }

    return lcaConverted;
  })
);
```

Which is pretty ugly and I'm looking for a "nicer" solution to this.

Is there an easy way available to do this by using the initial Observable (and receiving an Observable as output)?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: thats basically my problem - never worked really with observables (or transformations) just on a base of "receiving something and put it somewhere) - so i'm already failing on "where to start".

first approach was with "pipe" and then recreate objects with some foreachs over all data. but appearently there was no success at all.

Biggest problem: I dont know how to debug my intermediary results.

Comment: Sorry,  your goal It's not clear to me.. can you update with the code you tried so far?

Comment: added my current (working) solution, which is not very "nice" :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just looking for something a little cleaner? If so look into some of the newer array features instead of writing `for`:

```
this.data = getObservable({
        body: parameters
    }).pipe(
        map(lca => lca.map(entry => ({
                    name: entry.name,
                    series: entry.series.map(x => ({
                        name: new Date(x.name),
                        value: x.value
                    }))
                }))
            )
        );
```

Specifically `.map`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: yes, that was exactly what i was looking for (in special the map for arrays) - thanks a lot for your help!